# Second wifi network connected to main router

Tags: wireless-networking, home-networking

I do not own "main router" and I do not have any access besides wifi password and there are other people in the building that I have to share network with.

I want to add second router to my apartment network to separate other people and to have my own wifi network and only use internet connection from main network.

I assume I have to get some router with two radios (but not dual band, since I have eq that uses only 2,4GHz) but it is quite hard to find such router.
Second idea is to buy two wireless routers one would connect to main one and provide internet connection and other one would be connected with RJ-45 and I would be able to have different subnet for my own eq (GF laptop, mobile phones, etc.).
Third idea, however less convenient is that I use my laptop to connect to internet wifi, I connect second router by RJ-45 to my laptop so internet is passed from my laptop to secondary wifi and connect other eq to that wifi.
But then separation is not ideal and my GF would have to have my laptop always running.

Ideally I would like to have one additional wifi router so it would be cheaper.(Also that is why I ask question, to not spend money on some routers and fiddle with it and loose money)

So did anyone did something like this and can help me out, know some router that can be bridge to other network and access point at the same time?

(Bonus point if I could add mobile networking modem to it as backup when main internet connection is down or overloaded by neigbours)

Comment: Dual-band is fine, after all it's called that because it supports both 5 GHz *and* 2.4 GHz

Comment: @grawity But then I want to use one 2.4GHz radio to connect as bridge to main router. It would be ok if I could set second radio to 2.4GHz but I do not know if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need a Wi-Fi device that is capable of acting in `Bridge` mode. A number of the Edimax devices can certainly do this. You will typically see them marketed as Wi-Fi extenders. Just check that they are able to work as a Wi-Fi bridge.

In that mode, they will connect upstream to your building Wi-Fi and downstream will  create a new SSID.